# Regular expression to parse url after the domain name

Tags: regex, excel

Hi I'm trying to use regular expressions in an Excel sheet to grab the path components of an url. For instance from http://www.bccdc.ca/dis-cond/a-z/_c/Chickenpox/default.htm I need the regex to grab "dis-cond". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
   https?:\/\/.*?\/(.*?)\/
```

Or not escape char / like this:

```
   https?://.*?/(.*?)/
```

Path component is in group 1